# JSON NSDictionary showing null description when output to log

Tags: php, ios, sql, json

I'm learning some basic php, SQL, JSON so that I can use a database with my iOS programs. I'm having trouble when it comes to parsing this information inside my app. Here is my code but my NSLog shows (null) whenever I run it.

```
NSURLSessionConfiguration *config =
    [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];

    //@property (nonatomic, strong) NSURLSession *session;
    _session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:config delegate:self
        delegateQueue:nil];

//my test practice site url
NSString *requestString = @"http://sqlphp.site88.net/default.php";
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:requestString];
NSURLRequest *req = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

NSURLSessionDataTask *dataTask = [self.session dataTaskWithRequest:req 
    completionHandler: ^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {

    //@property (nonatomic) NSArray *databaseArray;
    self.databaseArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:nil];

    //shows (null) on log whenever ran
    NSLog(@"%@", self.databaseArray);         
}];
```

Feel free to jump to the website [by clicking here](http://sqlphp.site88.net/default.php) as well, but here is the JSON string if you don't want to click.

```
[{"id":"1","name":"pippo","surname":"Mr Pippo","age":"108"},{"id":"2","name":"Paperino","surname":"Mr Paperino","age":"109"}]
```

Does anyone have any idea what I'm doing wrong that it is not showing up as a string? I copied almost verbatim from Big Nerd Ranch book's example to practice this except they use a .json rather than .php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the NSError, they usually have the information you need to solve the error.

I changed your serialization line to this:

```
NSArray * databaseArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data
                                                          options:0
                                                          error:&error];
```

and then checked the content of error:

```
(lldb) po error
Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840
"The data couldn’t be read because it isn’t in the correct format."
(JSON text did not start with array or object
and option to allow fragments not set.)
UserInfo=0x60800046e680
```

So, with that info, I tried to read the actual content of data, and I got this:

```
(lldb) po [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:4]
<html>
 <head>
  <title>SQL To JSON Test</title>
 </head>
 <body>
[{"id":"1","name":"pippo","surname":"Mr Pippo","age":"108"},{"id":"2","name":"Paperino","surname":"Mr Paperino","age":"109"}]   
<!-- Hosting24 Analytics Code -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://stats.hosting24.com/count.php"></script>
<!-- End Of Analytics Code -->
```

So that's the issue!
Your webpage isn't returning just your JSON string, but an HTML file containing it!

Comment: Thanks! It seems the top of my script had some HTML in it and the bottom of it had some javascript to display ads from my host. That's fixed and it works now. Much appreciated!